# Navigating from the calendar event in the calendar to the list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

I have a form for the list and a calendar which adds the list event details. However, the process is that whenever someone click on the calendar event it goes in it and shows some details. But what I want is if someone click on the calendar event it will direct it to the list item rather than the event details in a calendar. I am using SharePoint Designer 2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear about your requirement - is it something, when you enter something in your calendar list, from then some of the calendar column should update the custom list?

If this is the requirement - you could create a sample workflow on calendar list on item creation event, this should copy that calendar column value to custom list.

And, if your requirement is just to navigate the hyperlink from calendar list to custom list - you could implement this using the js link webpart in calendar list.

**Sample example - how to use js link?** 
[SharePoint : Using JSLink with SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/sharepoint-using-jslink-with-sharepoint-2013)

[SharePoint 2013 jslink list view examples: Add header and footer to list view web part using JSLink in SharePoint Online/2013/2016](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-jslink-list-view-example/)

Comment: I have a question that will this Js link will be inserted in to calendar.js from the SharePoint or from the SharePoint library and assets?

Comment: @Noman: Sorry for the late reply, you could host your custom js script inside the asset library.